# Meta-tag only gets up to first word of string

Tags: express, handlebars.js, meta-tags

I'm using handlebars to send two meta tags into my handlebars file

The value of title is "Random Title"
The value of cta is "Call To Action"

```
<meta property="og:title" content={{title}}/>
<meta property="og:description" content={{cta}}/>
```

When I attempt to scrape the meta tags, the title shows up as 'Random', and the cta shows up as 'Call'. Why is it that the meta tags are only gathering the first word in the string?

Does anyone know how to make the meta tags take the entire string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer. You have to change it to

```
<meta property="og:title" content="{{title}}"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="{{cta}}"/>
```

This only applies when theres more than one word.